# Complete a partially filled transitive relation

Tags: matrices, algorithms, relations

Is there any particular algorithm to complete (as much you can) a partially filled transtive relation (given in matrix form)?

You can assume that the given partially filled matrix mat[1:n][1:n] is reflexive and symmetric.

For 1<=i<=n and 1<=j<=n, mat[i][j]=1 denotes that i and j are related, mat[i][j]=0 denotes that i and j are not related and mat[i][j]=-1 denotes that the relation between i and j is not known till now.

For example:

```
 1  1 -1  1 -1
 1  1  1 -1 -1
-1  1  1 -1 -1
 1 -1 -1  1  1
-1 -1 -1  1  1
```

will be filled as

```
 1  1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: The situation you ask about assumes the partial relation is reflexive and symmetric.  In this case the transitive closure remains reflexive and symmetric, so it gives an equivalence relation, i.e. a partition of the original domain of the partial relation.  In your example the partition winds up having a single block (all elements are equivalent).  If you are interested in this particular case, it is essentially finding the connected components of an undirected graph.  There are algorithms as well for the more general case of directed graphs.